# What is a preferred way for installing Karma in Angular/Django project?

Tags: javascript, python, django, angularjs, karma-runner

I am just starting on integrating AngularJS into my Django project.

After I installed Karma for testing following the tutorial I got bunch of Node.js modules installed in my root project folder.
Should I check all of this files from `node_modules` folder into my repo? Or should I ignore them with `.gitignore`?

Are there alternatives to installing Karma to root or is it required?

Comment: This really seems like 2 questions, one about ignoring all or some `node_modules` with Git and the other about whether `karma` needs to be in the root folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that you need to install a particular node module in a folder that encompasses all files that will use it. This is most easily accomplished by putting all node modules in the root folder of your website. This is by design of `node`'s creator, though I'm not sure if he wants it that way or just does not want to change it. Either way, there is no way around this.

As for `karma`, as it is a node module, it needs to be in a folder that includes all files that will use it; therefore, if your entire website uses it, you're better off putting it in the website's root folder.

Of course, as `node` is open source, you could go in & change this requirement of node modules so they can be installed anywhere, maybe with a pointer from a file that uses it to that node module.

Only you & your team (and your users) can determine if you want to push or ignore your website files, but in general with `node_modules`, if your users need them, send them. If only your developers need them, either install them individually on all developers' machines or make another branch for development work. `Node` also has a way to separate development modules from release modules, so you could look into that.

Comment: No problem, though I still think this should have been 2 questions.